# Calculate Total Amount for a specific period

Tags: filter, sum, dax

I want to calculate total value between two dates in DAX.  I have a formula SUM(C5:C16) in excel sheet, which C5 is the sales amount for a specific date (last year + 1month), and C16 is the sales amount for current row date.

I tried this formula in DAX, but it did not return **sum** value:

```
var Rolling  = CALCULATE(sum('proces'[HOURS]),DATESINPERIOD('Date'[DateField],ENDOFMONTH('proces'[date_start]),-12,MONTH))
```

Also, I tried this one, but it is not working:

```
   =SumX (
var prev=DATEADD(DATEADD('proces'[date_start]  ,-1,YEAR),+1,MONTH)
return 
Filter (  'proces', 
'proces'[date_end] <= Earlier ( 'proces'[date_end] ) &&

 'proces'[date_start]>=prev,
'proces'[HOURS])
```

Also, I tried this one but it returns nothing

```
    =CALCULATE(
            SUMX('proces','proces'[HOURS]),
            DATESBETWEEN(
'Date'[DateField],
STARTOFMONTH(DATEADD(LASTDATE('Date'[DateField]),-1,MONTH)),
ENDOFMONTH(DATEADD('Date'[DateField],-1,MONTH))
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about variables in DAX and your formulas are not even valid DAX expressions. Learn about variables in the official documentation:
[Use variables to improve your DAX formulas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/best-practices/dax-variables)

If you need further help with calculating the your total amount, add sample data to your question.